# How to fix mesh into a more uniform and simple version?

Tags: modeling, mesh, vertices, faces

I'm finding many issues with making a mesh for a 3d model more uniform. With the current state it is in; it looks messy, is hard to sculpt smoothly creates divots when the triangles don't line up, and generally makes the model look unprofessional. I was wondering if there is some sort of setting or modifier in blender that can fix this, or would i have to do it by hand?

The first picture is my model's arm, the second is mileena's arm from MKX which is what i would like my mesh to resemble.

[image: My messy model]

[image: mileena]

Answer (score 1):

This is called retopologizing, it is something that's necessary for animatable objects or game assets, there are a lot of addons that help with retopologizing, these ease the process, not replace it.

There are some automatic solutions, a free one is [Instant Meshes](https://github.com/wjakob/instant-meshes) this will require further corrections.

I recommend doing it by hand, enable F2 and Bsurface addons, this can be quite time consuming so you should be happy with your mesh before doing your retopo, always create quads, game engines will always triangulate your model but originally it probably was 95% quads.

Comment: Ah thank you!, i'll see what i can do with the options you suggested.